# FTP Client that supports UTF-16

Tags: ftp

I am trying to find an FTP client that support UTF-16 encoding.  I have music that is stored on a NAS and would like to access it outside.  The problem is trying to display and access the music which the folders and files are stored as Japanese, Korean, and Thai script.  I have tried FireFTP and WinSCP, but these FTP client are not displaying the folders and filenames correctly nor am I able traverse them.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that Filezilla can do UTF-16.

Comment: I tried Filezilla (specifying UTF-16), but it still doesn't work correctly.  I will need to do additional research to see what is going on.